# Autotools: Convert x86_64 to amd64 and so on

Tags: gnu, packaging, autotools, autoconf, deb

I am trying to enable packaging for my C project. I know that i can use the  `AC_CANONICAL_BUILD` macro to get `@build_cpu@`. But the problem is, that the debian `control` file wants `amd64` instead of `x86_64`. Is there a simple way to convert these `uname` outputs to the format that `dpkg` wants or do I need to check every possible architecture in an if statement?

Comment: Just as a note: @build_cpu@ is not what you think it is, you want @host_cpu@: https://autotools.io/autoconf/canonical.html

Comment: So i thought, that `@build_cpu@` is the CPU that I am building for and `@host_cpu@` is the CPU of my build system, no matter for what type I am building?

Comment: You have them the wrong way around, see the link: CBUILD is the system you're running on, CHOST the one you're running the generated binaries on. I wrote more about that (with drawings! :D) at blog.flameeyes.eu/s/canonical-target some years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, and why you would need this mapping. My impression is that you might probably be trying to do something wrong.

For packages that are portable, you should simply use one of the wildcards for the Architecture field. For example **any**, or if for whatever reason it's kernel specific, then something like **linux-any** or **kfreebsd-any**.

If you really need to map between GNU triplets or components and dpkg architectures you can always use the dpkg-architecture command (please check its man page), but again, this usually smells like the wrong way of going about this, and more so from an upstream point of view, which should be distribution neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use sed in your autotools file to do these conversions?  For example,

```
echo `uname -m | sed s/aarch64/arm64/ | sed s/x86_64/amd64/`
```

will output arm64 on an ARM aarch64 system and amd64 on an x86_64 system.

I happen to be using this at the moment to automate installation of Visual Studio Code Server for multiple architectures like this:

```
export VERSION=3.12.0 \
&& export ARCH=`uname -m | sed s/aarch64/arm64/ | sed s/x86_64/amd64/` \
&& curl -fOL https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/v$VERSION/code-server_"$VERSION"_"$ARCH".deb \
&& dpkg -i code-server_"$VERSION"_"$ARCH".deb \
&& rm code-server_"$VERSION"_"$ARCH".deb
```